# ajax tooltip doesn't load the data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web, tooltip

I am making a web site in mvc structure. This site shows a table and on that table there is a tooltip which shows more detail of the cell. However, the data in tooltip is not loaded. (except tooltip everything works fine)
This tooltip data is loaded from mySQL and it has two input variables deptName and deptPart.
Tooltip worked well when I typed in random things instead of loading data...I can't find a reason why it gets an error :(

My Model for tooltip is

```
function getTooltipML($deptName, $deptPart)
{
    $sql = "Call TooltipML('$deptName', '$deptPart')";
    $tooltipML = $this->sqlExecution($sql);
    return json_encode($tooltipML);
}

function getTooltipWillLeave($deptName, $deptPart)
{
    $sql = "Call TooltipWillLeave('$deptName', '$deptPart')";
    $tooltipWL = $this->sqlExecution($sql);
    return json_encode($tooltipWL);
}
```

My Controller for tooltip is

```
function view()
    {   
        $deptName = $_POST['deptName'];
        $deptPart = $_POST['deptPart'];
        $tooltipML = $this ->model -> getTooltipML($deptName, $deptPart);
        $tooltipWL = $this ->model -> getTooltipWillLeave($deptName, $deptPart);
        //call view to push the data into the view
        $this->requireView('ManagementMasterView', [
            'page' => "DashboardDetail",
            'tooltipML' =>$tooltipML,
            'tooltipWL' => $tooltipWL
            ]);
    }

    function tooltip(){
        $deptName = $_POST['deptName'];
        $deptPart = $_POST['deptPart'];
        echo json_encode ($this -> model -> getTooltipML($deptName, $deptPart));
        echo json_encode ($this -> model -> getTooltipWillLeave($deptName, $deptPart));
    }
```

My view for the tooltip is

```
<div class="dash_table_container">
    <?php
    // pre-process data
    $printedData = json_decode($data['resourceStatus'], true);
    $tableHeader = ['deptName', 'deptPart', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
    $tooltipData1 = json_decode($data['tooltipMLEx'], true);
    $tooltipData2 = json_decode($data['tooltipWL'], true);
    // //Build up a table
    table1('dash-tb1', $tableHeader, $printedData, $tooltipData1, $tooltipData2);
    ?>
</div>
```

//function below is in separate php file but I just added in view here for better readability

```
function table1($tableId, $header, $data, $tooltip1, $tooltip2){
// header build
    echo '
    <table class="display table table-striped" id="'.$tableId.'">
        <thead>
            
            <tr class="table-primary">
            <th>#</th>';
        foreach ($header as $columnVal){
        echo '<th>'.$columnVal.'</th>';
        }

    echo '
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';
        $index = 0;
        $tooltip1 = "";
        $tooltip2 = "";
             foreach ($data as $row){
                $tooltip1;
                $tooltip2;
                $index++;
                echo '
                <tr id="'.$row['deptName'].'" data-id="'.$row['deptPart'].'">
                <td>'.$index.'</td>
                <td>'.$row['deptName'].'</td><td>'.$row['deptPart'].'</td><td>'.$row['C'].'</td>
                <td class = "CellWithComment"><span class="CellComment">'.$tooltip1.'</span>'.$row['D'].'</td>
                <td class = "CellWithComment"><span class="CellComment">'.$tooltip2.'</span>'.$row['E].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['F'].'</td>';
                    
             }                                
    echo '
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>';
            }
```

and my javascript is

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add tooltip
  $('.CellComment').tooltip({
   delay: 500,
   placement: "bottom",
   title: tooltipDetails,
   html: true
  }); 
});

// Get employee details for tooltip
function tooltipDetails(deptName, deptPart){
  var deptName = this.deptName;
  var deptPart = $(this).attr('data-id');
  var tooltipText = "";
  $.ajax({
   url: '/hrmsystem/Dashboard/tooltip',
   method: "POST",
   data: {dept_Name:deptName, dept_Part:deptPart},
   dataType: "JSON",
   async: false,
   success: function(response){
     tooltipText = response;
   }
  });
  return tooltipText;
}
```

Thank you very much for your tips.

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot? Does the function run? What are the values of `deptName` and `deptPart`? Does the request hit your url? Is data received? Do you get a response back? Do you get any errors?

Comment: all the functions except the tooltip one works well. deptName and deptPart are the input variables of query to get tooltip data. Data is not received. If I enter the URL it returns empty json. No response back...only the table without tooltip appears